# HTML anchor within Javascript variable assigned dynamically to a dataTable cell is not rendered by the browser

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I have implemented a dataTable on dynamic set of data.  There is a javascript variable that contains the following:

```
var path = "/<a href="http://demo.example.com/first.html">First</a>/<a href="http://demo.example.com/second.html">Second</a>/";
```

This variable is supposed to have two anchors.  When I assign this variable dynamically to a cell of a dataTable as follows:

```
var tab = document.getElementById("sample_table");
var objCells = tab.rows.item(i).cells;
objCells[0].innerHTML = path;
```

It is shown as plain text within the table cell and is not rendered as HTML by the browser:

```
/<a href="http://demo.example.com/first.html">First</a>/<a href="http://demo.example.com/second.html">Second</a>/
```

and I want it like this:

/[First](http://demo.example.com/first.html)/[Second](http://demo.example.com/second.html)/

What should be done to render it correctly in the browser?

Comment: Your path string is incorrect. `var path = "<a href='http://demo.example.com/first.html'>First</a>/<a href='http://demo.example.com/second.html'>Second</a>/";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var path = `/<a href="http://demo.example.com/first.html">First</a>/<a href="http://demo.example.com/second.html">Second</a>/`;
var tab = document.getElementById("table1");
var objCells = tab.rows.item(0).cells;
objCells[0].innerHTML = path;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<table id='table1' border=1>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

try using JavaScript template literals,
Instead of using single quote using the ` letter

Comment: path value is received from server side through Perl code.  So I do this var path_name = '\`' + path + '\`';  and I get this: "\`/<a href="http://demo.example.com/first.html">First</a>/<a href="http://demo.example.com/second.html">Second</a>/\`"

Comment: Don't use the single quote at all, put only the ` characters : var path_name = `` + path + ``;

Comment: I tried same: var path_name = `` + path + ``; and I get this: "/<a href="demo.example.com/first.html">First</a>/<a href="demo.example.com/second.html">Second</a>/", quotes are shown when I do view source, in user interface, I see this: /<a href="demo.example.com/first.html">First</a>/<a href="demo.example.com/second.html">Second</a>/

Comment: if you are not receiving any errors in the console then, my best guess is that the html you are receiving is incorrect, maybe there is a space or other characters between the < and the 'a' in which cause it to be rendered as plain text instead of html

Comment: I found the issue, I was using ascii codes '&lt;' for < and '&gt;' for >, for handling in Perl code, though these characters were converted correctly to < and >, but html was not rendering correctly.  I converted these characters before assigning them to variable path, and then it came correct.  Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var path = "<a href='http://demo.example.com/first.html'>First</a>/<a href='http://demo.example.com/second.html'>Second</a>/";

document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = path;
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I need to assign this value to a cell of a dataTable, it is a part of dataTable, so can't use <div>.

Comment: I simply showed example, you can assign it to your `dataTable`. Your path string was incorrect.

Comment: Even with single quotes in path string, I get the same error.

Comment: I get this: /<a href='http://demo.example.com/first.html'>First</a>/<a href='http://demo.example.com/second.html'>Second</a>/ , and not the hyperlinks: /First/Second/

Answer (score -1):

You could use the draw method also

```
<html>
<body> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function () {
            var tab = $('#example').DataTable();
            var path = "/<a href='http://demo.example.com/first.html'>First</a>/<a href='http://demo.example.com/second.html'>Second</a>/";


            tab.cell(0, 0).data(path).draw();
        });
    </script>
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</body>
</html>
```